# How to remove brackets and number form string in jquery

Tags: jquery

My String:

```
var string = 'Testing(10)';
```

I want to remove '(10)' form string with usign jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need jquery for this:

You can do it like this: `string.replace(/ *\([^)]*\)*/g, "")`

**Demo**

```js
var string = 'Testing(10)';


console.log(string.replace(/ *\([^)]*\)*/g, ""))
```